# Where did the convention of using variable names foo and bar come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Often when showing simple examples, or pseudo-code variables/classes/methods etc. with names `foo` and `bar` turn up.

When, how and why did this convention come about?

Comment: lost in the mists of time,probably the Mayans when they were programming the great cycle.

Comment: See RFC 3092. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's known precisely, but there's interesting history in the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar#History_and_etymology).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it derived from [FUBAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR)